# FullSeriesCollection issues

Tags: excel, vba, plot

I am using the following code to plot a graph:

```
Set Date_Rng = range("Time_Series_Dates_1")

Set Rng_1 = range("Time_Series_1")
Sheet10.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
With ActiveChart
  .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Rng_1
   .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dates"
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "£ GDP"
  .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
  .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Date_Rng
 End With
```

I am then trying to do the following:

```
           Selection.Formula = _
    "=SERIES(,'Tool v13.xlsm'!Time_Series_Dates_1,'Tool v13.xlsm'!Time_Series_1,1)"
```

and I get an object-defined error! What am I doing wrong please?
 I have tried this:

```
  With ActiveChart
   .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    "=='Tool v13.xlsm'!Time_Series_1"

   .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dates"
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "£ GDP"
  .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
  .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Date_Rng
 End With
```

But no luck. Could there be anything wrong with my named range?

Comment: When you Debug what line are you getting the error at?

Comment: Selection.Formula = _
    "=SERIES(,'Tool v13.xlsm'!Time_Series_Dates_1,'Tool v13.xlsm'!Time_Series_1,1)"

Comment: or FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    "=='Tool v13.xlsm'!Time_Series_1"

Comment: "Application-defined or object-defined error"